# Racket hash-table default failure result unhelpful

Tags: racket

In Racket, if you try to `hash-ref` for a key the hash does not contain, e.g.

```
(define a-hash #hash((1 . "a")
                     (2 . "b")))
(hash-ref a-hash 3)
```

An `exn:fail:contract` is raised.

> ...\Racket\collects\racket\private\more-scheme.rkt:263:2: hash-ref: no value found for key

Unfortunately, `exn:fail:contract` is unhelpfully broad. It's the same type of exception you get if you try to apply a value as a procedure

```
(with-handlers ((exn:fail? print))
  (10 11))
```

> (exn:fail:contract "application: not a procedure;\n expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments\n  given: 10\n  arguments...:\n   11" #)

Is there any way to change the default value of `hash-ref`'s `failure-result` from outside the code using it? Could I go into my Racket installation and change it there? That seems Bad and Dangerous. What are my options? I could parse the exception message, but that reeks of hacky and error-prone.

Comment: Are you unable to pass in a different `failure-result`?

Comment: I'm not calling hash-ref directly, I'm calling code that calls it

Comment: Ah ok. I would file a bug against the code that calls `hash-ref` then.

Comment: Kind of a band-aid though, don't you think? `hash-ref` should have a more specific exception imo.

Comment: I think a default value should be general. But that is why `hash-ref` allows the programmer to give a different `failure-result`. Are you looking at a specific library in Racket?

Comment: I looked at private/more-scheme.rkt in a few recent versions of Racket and can't find a `hash-ref` usage anywhere near line 263 (from the error message). The earliest use of `hash-ref` in that file is for definitions of things like `hash-update`. So I'm curious what version of Racket this is? (And whether more-scheme.rkt has already been modified?)

Comment: Line 263 for me is `(define (call-with-exception-handler exnh thunk)`. I'm reasonably certain I'm using the normal version of Racket., and DrRacket reports that it's up-to-date.

Comment: OK. Reason I looked there was to try to guess the answer to stchang's question to you: What function are you calling that in turn calls `hash-ref`? Because really this seems like a situation where _that_ function doesn't expect `hash-ref` to fail -- and _that's_ the place to change. Otherwise, I don't think you can monkey-patch `hash-ref` in the way you wondered. Which leaves only the option of the exn msg parse hack idea.

Answer (score 1):

There is `failure-result` in [hash-ref](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/hashtables.html?q=hash-ref&q=oracle#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._hash-ref%29%29).

```
(define a-hash #hash((1 . "a")
                     (2 . "b")))
(hash-ref a-hash 3 #f) ; => #f
```